# Rank reaches -1 in google play services (Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I made a simple game in unity, and I implemented google play services using [This Plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) and I have encountered some issue which I can't find any solution simply by searching on google btw I have already read the docs and made a custom skin/ui for my leaderboard as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK7Ps.jpg) and this works fine (that not registered text is intentional) but the issue I am getting is that some of my tester can't even login to google play and some can
and even one of them got a rank of -1 [see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HxXK.jpg), idk how this happened but we can't access the database to edit the data manually(or without editing code/creating new leaderboard).

the codes I am using:-

This one is for authenticating and loading the leaderboard

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;

public class GPauth : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool IsConnected = false;
public GameObject Lockbtn;
public Button btn;

public Transform EntryContainer;
public Transform EntryTemplate;

public float TemplateHeight = 300f;

public TextMeshProUGUI PlayerName;
public TextMeshProUGUI PlayerRank;
public TextMeshProUGUI PlayerScore;

GooglePlayData data;
PlayerData playerData;

public GameObject scroeDisplay;
public GameObject newtya;
public GameObject mainMenu;
public GameObject lbUI;

[SerializeField] private AudioSource LockSFX;
[SerializeField] private Animator LockAnime;
[SerializeField] private AudioSource source;

private bool LeaderboardDataHasFilled;

private void Start()
{
    playerData = SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();
    data = SaveSystem.LoadConsole();
    if(data == null || playerData == null || playerData.HasPlayed == false)
    {
        Lockbtn.SetActive(true);
        SaveSystem.SaveConsole(this);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        IsConnected = data.connectedToGooglePlay;
    }
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    AuthenticateUser();
    LeaderboardDataHasFilled = false;
}

private void AuthenticateUser()
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
}

private void ProcessAuthentication(SignInStatus status)
{
    if (status == SignInStatus.Success)
    {
        IsConnected = true;
    }
    else IsConnected = false;
    SaveSystem.SaveConsole(this);
}

public void ShowLeaderboard()
{
    if(data == null || playerData == null || playerData.HasPlayed == false)
    {
        LockSFX.Play();
        LockAnime.SetBool("Start", true);
        Invoke("resetLockAnime", 0.1f);
    }
    else
    {
        source.Play();
        if (!IsConnected) AuthenticateUser();
        else LeaderboardUI();
   }

   

}
private void resetLockAnime()
{
    LockAnime.SetBool("Start", false);

}

private void LeaderboardUI()
{



    scroeDisplay.SetActive(false);
    mainMenu.SetActive(false);
    newtya.SetActive(false);
    lbUI.SetActive(true);

    if (LeaderboardDataHasFilled) return;

    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.LoadScores(
        GPGSIds.leaderboard_newtya,
        LeaderboardStart.TopScores,
        10,
        LeaderboardCollection.Public,
        LeaderboardTimeSpan.AllTime,
        (data) =>
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Data Was Null");
                return;
            }
            /*Public Leaderboard database logic starts here*/
            // get scores
            IScore[] scores = data.Scores;
             // get user ids
            string[] userIds = new string[scores.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.Length; i++)
            {
                userIds[i] = scores[i].userID;
            }
            // forward scores with loaded profiles
            Social.LoadUsers(userIds, profiles => DisplayLeaderboardEntries(scores, profiles, data.PlayerScore));
            /*Public Leaderboard database logic Ends here*/

            if (data.PlayerScore == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Data.PlayerScore was null");
                PlayerName.text = "Not registered";
                return;
            }
            if (data.PlayerScore.userID == null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Data.PlayerScore.UserID was null");
                PlayerName.text = "Not registered";
                return;
            }
            IScore pScore = data.PlayerScore;
            string userId = data.PlayerScore.userID;
            string[] PlayerIDS = new string[] { userId };
            Social.LoadUsers(PlayerIDS, profiles => PlayerScoreSetup(pScore, profiles));
        });
    LeaderboardDataHasFilled = true;
}

private void PlayerScoreSetup(IScore data, IUserProfile[] profiles)
{
    PlayerName.text = profiles[0].userName.ToString();
    PlayerScore.text = data.formattedValue.ToString();
    PlayerRank.text = data.rank.ToString();
}

private void DisplayLeaderboardEntries(IScore[] scores, IUserProfile[] profiles, IScore playerData)
{
    EntryTemplate.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    for (int i = 0; i < profiles.Length; i++)
    {
       Transform entryTransform = Instantiate(EntryTemplate, EntryContainer);
            RectTransform entryRectTransform = entryTransform.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            entryRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, -TemplateHeight * i);

            entryRectTransform.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        
        
            TextMeshProUGUI txRank = entryRectTransform.Find("RankTXT").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            TextMeshProUGUI txName = entryRectTransform.Find("NameTXT").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
            TextMeshProUGUI txScore = entryRectTransform.Find("ScoreTXT").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();

            txRank.text = scores[i].rank.ToString();
            txName.text = profiles[i].userName.ToString();
            txScore.text = scores[i].formattedValue.ToString();
        
    }
}

}
```

and this one runs when player loses to upload the score

```
long scoreforlb = Convert.ToInt64(HighScore);
        Social.ReportScore(scoreforlb, GPGSIds.leaderboard_newtya, UpdateLeaderboard);

  //to check if score was reported or not
private void UpdateLeaderboard(bool success)
    {
        if (success) Debug.Log("Success");
        else Debug.Log("err");
    }
```

I have already implemented some checks to prevent above code to run if user isnot connect to google play games.
Any help will be very appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience **'-1' rank is caused by player's Google Play profile's *Game Activity* being set to private**.

Players have the option to set this preference during initial creation of google play games account, or they can change it later in the play games app ('Game Activity' setting under 'Profile and privacy').

One solution (which I used) is to show a help button (to players with -1 rank) which shows a message box explaining why the rank is not available and how the player can set their profile to public if they want to see their rank.

Regarding the login problem, you can see the reason for login failure in the SignInStatus returned in authentication callback, which might point out the issue.
Also check to see if the tester is able to sign into other games which use google play games, to make sure it is not a device/account issue.